# Why when I export .fbx file with fabric texture and import it then it becomes very ugly?

Tags: texturing, uv, export, import, .fbx

I made a sofa model in blender and add fabric texture in it. But when I export it into fbx file and then import it its fabric texture become very stretchy and ugly.[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you scale texture in nodes. It isn't supported in fbx file format. You should scale UV itself instead